# Python - Django remove unsafe character from string

Tags: python, html, django, character

I am currently doing a search on my website with the following character :

q=increase%0B%0B

These two characters imply an error, and my search doesn't return anything. If I only search for increase, without the two lasts, the search works. Is it a way to make it html safe by removing all the unsafe characters as those ones ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why is that parameter being generated in the first place?

Comment: Because a malicious user entered it.

Comment: Sounds to me then that ignoring it is the correct thing to do.

Comment: `'increase%0B%0B'.replace('%0B', '')` => `'increase'` (captain obvious)

Comment: `import re` `re.sub('%..', '', 'increase%0B%0B')` => `'increase'`

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the best solution to my problem.
http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/05/20/stripping-control-characters-in-python.html

It allows to have a much more generic and elegant solution.